# Why am I constantly being redirected to stackexchange.com/promos?

Tags: bug

I have to close my browser to make it stop. If I try to go to [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com) it redidects me to https://stackexchange.com/promos

What's going on??

Comment: Why do you have to close your browser *"to make it stop"*? Isn't the redirect just once? What if you do not include the `www` prefix?